# Kineticjs - Rotate image clockwise 90 degrees

Tags: rotation, kineticjs

I am really liking kineticjs lib but I am struggling to find any resource/examples on rotating  a kinetic image object.

I have seen many on rotating shapes but all seem, from looking, like they rotate the whole canvas and not the image object.

Is this true and If not, could anyone point out any documentation please?

regards

p.s.

for those who want code, It's just the standard image deleration:

```
mainImage = new Kinetic.Image({
    image: imageObj,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    draggable: true,
    startScale: 1
});
```

and have tried:

```
function rotateLeft(){
    $('#rotate-left').bind( $bind, function(){
        mainImage.rotate(90);
        layer.draw();
    });
}
```

which makes the image disappear...

regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kinetic.Image inherits rotateDeg and rotate -methods from Kinetic.Node -class. rotateDeg is the one you are looking for. rotate is the same, but uses radians instead of degrees. 
These will rotate relative to the current rotation.

There are also setRotate and setRotateDeg -methods, which will set the rotation to some absolute value.

So try this:

```
mainImage.rotateDeg(90);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I found that the image was actually rotating, but off the page, using `mainImage.setOffset( mainImage.getWidth()/2,mainImage.getHeight()/2 );` bound to the touchstart event kept the offset centered and worked. Thank you anyway

Comment: you do not have to bound     mainImage.setOffset( mainImage.getWidth()/2,mainImage.getHeight()/2 ); to touchstart event, just specify the offsets at the time of creation and it will always rotate about the center.

Comment: Don't forget to re-draw the layer with layer.draw(); after doing these manipulations.